# React Typescript: Access Variable with forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, foreach, syntax

I use a `forEach` to access each `string` in `countTargetOptions` which is an array of properties that I want to access for the `targetData` variable.

How can I use `element` to get each `targetData` property? My code below shows incorrect syntax as it prints `undefined`.

```
const countTargetOptions = [
  "count_targets",
  "count_targets_excluded",
  "count_targets_pending",
  "count_targets_in_progress",
  "count_targets_completed",
  "count_targets_failed",
];

 countTargetOptions.forEach((element: string) =>{
    console.log(targetData.element);
   });
```

Comment: What is `targetData` and where does it come from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: In addition to *that* problem, unless your `targetData` has an `element` property this shouldn't even *compile*, much less run. You'd need to set `countTargetOptions` to explicitly be `keyof typeof targetData`.

Comment: @JaredSmith when I do the brackets, I am still getting undefined. Note, without the loop I am able to access the data with `targetData.count_targets` (or any other property). Any further suggestions?

Comment: "Any further suggestions?" Yes. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run. Telling us about your problem in English does not help us help you. That linked dupe fixes a real problem with your code, although maybe not the one you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `targetData` is an object with all the keys present in `countTargetOptions`.

```
const countTargetOptions = [
  "count_targets",
  "count_targets_excluded",
  "count_targets_pending",
  "count_targets_in_progress",
  "count_targets_completed",
  "count_targets_failed",
];

 countTargetOptions.forEach((element: string) =>{
    console.log(targetData[element]);
   });
```

Also note, `countTargetOptions` should probably be typed as Array`where`XXXX`is the type of`targetData`.